# Do i need to install sql server for to run a database embedded program ?

Tags: sql-server

i made a java database project . I create a exe file of that program . I want to use it another computer . I used Microsoft sql database in my program .Do i need to install the microsoft sql to the user pc for every single time whenever i want to use it to another computer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make one computer as `server`, install the MS SQL Server on it, and all other client computers can access the `server`'s database, or, as you say, install every time when you want to use that program on other computers.

Comment: Actually i  made  a Beverage Management System using Java .there is stock , invoice ,Daily transaction etc .i used sql server to retrieve  data from database . I create exe file of my project . I want to use it for amy another computer . But the another computer that i ran the .exe file , it could not retrieve data from sql server though i install sql server on the computer also .I create same database on sql server in the another computer . But it didn't work . it just open the project , can open the UI's